# apache Hadoop-2.0.0 aplha version installation in full cluster using fedration

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins, hadoopy

I had installed hadoop stable version successfully. but confused while installing hadoop -2.0.0 version.

I want to install hadoop-2.0.0-alpha on two nodes, using federation on both machines. rsi-1, rsi-2 are hostnames.

what should be values of below properties for implementation of federation. Both machines are also used for datanodes too.

fs.defaulFS dfs.federation.nameservices dfs.namenode.name.dir dfs.datanode.data.dir yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address yarn.resourcemanager.address

One more point, in stable version of hadoop i have configuration files under conf folder in installation directory.

But in 2.0.0-aplha version, there is etc/hadoop directory and it doesnt have mapred-site.xml, hadoop-env.sh. do i need to copy conf folder under share folder into hadoop-home directory? or do i need to copy these files from share folder into etc/hadoop directory?

Regards, Rashmi

Answer (score 0):

You can run hadoop-setup-conf.sh in sbin folder. It instructs you step-by-step to configure. 
Please remember when it asks you to input the directory path, you should use full link
e.g., when it asks for conf directory, you should input /home/user/Documents/hadoop-2.0.0/etc/hadoop
After completed, remember to check every configuration file in etc/hadoop.
As my experience, I modified JAVA_HOME variable in hadoop-env.sh and some properties in core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml.
Regards